# How to add an assignment tab in Microsoft Teams without having Education license

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am developing desktop application using Microsoft Graph API. Application needs to write feedback for a specific assignment on Teams. The problem is that I don’t have an Assignment tab in Teams and I can’t test the application. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: If i am not wrong, you need to have the license to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re working for a software company, you can choose to become a Microsoft Partner. The cheapest way is by buying the **Action Pack** which costs $400 if I’m correct.

Once you’re a Microsoft Partner, you can go to demos.microsoft.com and request a Demo tenant for testing applications (be sure to pick the education demo tenant)

If it’s for a brief test, and you can figure out my e-mailadres (see it as a quest, you should be able to). I can maybe provide you with an temp account for a few days.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I will do this another way and if I fail, I will contact you.

Comment: @Goga consider marking one of these answer as the answer. That way you can signal StackOverflow that the asker got what he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You would require a Teams Education License in order for using Assignment Tab. [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/teams-for-education-02484392-d527-4342-983b-37d7b13f3f3a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) are the further details.